# to find the count of how many time a specific number occurred in multiple columns against each row

Tags: python, group-by, count, pandas-groupby

df = [image]

expected output : [image]

i want count of number 6 occurred for each row .

so for e.g for x1: number 6 has been repeated for 2 times in column a3 and a6. so the count is 2 for x1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can do this like this:

```
(df == 6).sum(axis=1)
```